# BigQuery: How to update the storage billing model via SQL for multiple datasets / in batch?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets?hl=en#update_storage_billing_models), it should be possible in Google Big Query to update the storage billing model via SQL for multiple datasets with a `FOR ... IN` loop. However, the given example statement failed for me

```sql
FOR record IN
 (SELECT CONCAT(catalog_name, ':', schema_name) AS dataset_path
 FROM PROJECT_ID.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA)
DO
 ALTER SCHEMA record.dataset_path
 SET OPTIONS(
   storage_billing_model = 'physical');
END FOR;
```

with the error

```
Not found: Project record at [5:2]
```

There is also an updated version of that script that reads

```sql
FOR record IN
 (SELECT CONCAT(catalog_name, '.', schema_name) AS dataset_path
 FROM PROJECT_ID.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA)
DO
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   "ALTER SCHEMA `" || record.dataset_path || "` SET OPTIONS(storage_billing_model = 'BILLING_MODEL')";
END FOR;
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything, I always got the result

```
There is no data to display.
```

and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- all queries are run in the [Big Query UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery)
- the [execution location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations?hl=en) was set to auto-detect, resulting in `US`, but all our datasets are hosted in `EU`
- changing the location via `MORE > Query setting > Advanced options` fixed the issue (disable `Automatic location selection` and select the correct value under `Location type`)

[image]

**Bonus**

We use the following statement now, as it's a little more flexible in terms of which datasets we want to modify:

```sql
FOR record IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  "PROJECT_ID.dataset"
  ]) as id)
DO
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   "ALTER SCHEMA `" || record.id || "` SET OPTIONS(storage_billing_model = 'PHYSICAL')";
END FOR;
```

[image]

---

**Some more information**

The first example (NOT using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) seems to be "just wrong" (i.e. I never got that to work at all).

The second example does work, BUT it's important to ensure the correct [execution location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations?hl=en), otherwise `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` won't return anything.

In our case, all our datasets are located in the `EU` multi-region, but the default for the execution is `US`. Since no datasets exist in `US`

```sql
 (SELECT CONCAT(catalog_name, '.', schema_name) AS dataset_path
 FROM PROJECT_ID.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA)
```

returns an empty result and the `FOR ... IN` loop isn't executed at all. Explicitly defining the location via

```sql
 (SELECT CONCAT(catalog_name, '.', schema_name) AS dataset_path
 FROM `PROJECT_ID.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`)
```

returns the expected results (i.e. datasets) - BUT altering the schema via

```sql
FOR record IN
 (SELECT CONCAT(catalog_name, '.', schema_name) AS dataset_path
 FROM `PROJECT_ID.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`)
DO
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   "ALTER SCHEMA `" || record.dataset_path || "` SET OPTIONS(storage_billing_model = 'PHYSICAL')";
END FOR;
```

still doesn't work and fails with the error

```
Not found: PROJECT_ID:region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA was not found in location US at [2:3]
```

The error kinda gives away, that the execution is still happening in location `US` and we actually need to change it in the query settings (see tl;dr at the top).